# How come I can see the reputation history of other users?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

If I go to some other user's profile and look at the `Activity` tab, then `reputation` tab, I can see the history of her/his reputation, including downvotes. Is this a privilege obtained at some reputation level? Or is it standard? I'm asking because I looked at the [help page for privileges](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) but there doesn't seem to exist any privilege like that.

Comment: I opened a "private" browser window (where I am logged out from CV) and checked that I could still see users' reputation history. So it's not a privilege.

Comment: You see downvotes that they may have received but not details on downvotes that they may have given.

Comment: @NickCox so, I shouldn't see the -1 people get when downvoting others. I should only be able to see the -2 they received, because someone else downvoted their questions/answers, or -5 because their answers were unupvoted, but not the -1 because they gave downvotes. Is this correct?

Comment: This is system-wide behavior, & it is part of the design intended by the developers.

Comment: On a browser where I am logged out, I cannot see reputation changes from downvotes that I've given.

Comment: @gung that makes sense: otherwise, it would be relatively easy to de-anonymize downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to hack the system.

#### Data explorer

I could not find anything here. The following query is the closest thing

https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/847098/user-reputation-history

you can find:

```
Upvotes Question
Upvote Answer
Downvotes own Q And A
Accepted Answers
Suggested Edits
Bounties Started
Bounties Received.
```

but not down votes other Q&A

#### Daily reputation status

This is the closest that I could get. The daily reputation can not be viewed by data explorer but the little graph shows daily reputation. I went to a user from which I knew that he/she gave a recent down vote (expressed in a recent meta-post). And indeed if you count all the points that you can see in data explorer (or the activity overview) and compare with the graph then you can see a discrepancy of 1 for a particular day. So you would be able, with quite some effort, to deduce the day at which another user has given a down vote.